# How does one contribute a blog post?

Tags: support

A fellow contributor to Stack Exchange Christianity suggested I make an answer of mine a blog post.  How do I go about doing that?  He gave me a hyperlink which led me to some blog posts, but I didn't happen to see any instructions there as to how to submit a contribution.

Answer (score 4):

tbh the blog is kind of dead right now, though we're interested in potentially reviving it.

Typically how the blog has worked in the past is that we'd take a topic and give four viewpoints on it represented various traditions.

However if folks want to prepare posts for the blog in a more ad-hoc manner I'm interested in running them. I've unfrozen the [blog chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2567/eschewmenical-blog-room), feel free to drop me a ping there and we can talk a bit more about what you're thinking and how we can make it happen.